# Does anyone know the name of this fantasy book series from about 10 to 12 years ago

Tags: story-identification, books

Clues:

- There were four main characters (three guys, one girl)
- They had been each been gifted a gem that had mysterious powers to unlock
- They were each talented at their own weapon; a sword, a bow, an axe, and dagger (the dude who used a dagger was super brainy and made pots, explosives, and had all of the good ideas)
- They fought creatures like dragons, ogres, and undead witches

Sorry, I don't remember any more. This was about 10 to 12 years ago.